# Windows Terminal Tab shortcuts don't work, Incorrect Type, Expected Object

Tags: json, windows-terminal

[image: No keyboard shortcut options to jump to profile]

When I look at the settings.json file, the keys ctrl+shift+NUMBER are supposed to jump to a certain console profile, but they don't see, to work. Looking at it through Visual Studio Code, the error message is 'Incorrect Type. Expected "object".

[image: Error shown in VS Code]

Key bindings in settings.json:

```
"keybindings": [
    {
        "command": "closePane",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+w"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "copy",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "duplicateTab",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+d"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTab",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+t"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile0",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile1",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile2",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile3",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile4",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+5"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile5",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+6"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile6",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+7"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile7",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+8"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "newTabProfile8",
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+shift+9"
        ]
    },
```

Is there an issue with the way my settings.json file is structured?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to structure your keybindings to open a new tab using the command structure:

`{ "action": "newTab", "index": 0 }`

The profiles are just an array and are accessed for keybindings by their index rather than their `name`. So you can access the first 9 profiles to open in a new tab like this:

```
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 0 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+1" },
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 1 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+2" },
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 2 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+3" },
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 3 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+4" },
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 4 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+5" },
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 5 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+6" },
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 6 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+7" },
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 7 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+8" },
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 8 }, "keys": "ctrl+shift+9" }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I did the same thing for the switchToTab actions, and now everything is working just fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help out.